# Is there a simple way using REST to get a list of forests attached to MarkLogic Database

Tags: rest, marklogic, marklogic-8

Here is my REST call:

```
curl -s --anyauth -u admin:pass -X GET -i http://myhost:8002/manage/v2/databases/MyDB/properties
```

I'd like to get a list of forests from this instead of all the properties. Something like:

```
MyDB001
MyDB002
MyDB003
etc.
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Lets start with the basics: Do not under-estimate the value of piointing your browser at the manage endpoint: `http://yourdomain:8002/manage/v2`.  From here, you can navigate and explore. Plus, the data available from the properties views are valid XML and JSON configurations for you to possibly re-use later on such as fetching via Curl. You can get these by passing the format=[xml or json]

**From there, lets look at the options:**

*Just want the names and IDs?*
Minimal information is available under the relations section.

```
http://yourdomain:8002/manage/v2/databases/yourdatabase
```

*Want more info?*
Useful when you have a cluster and want the details of hosts/paths/etc

```
http://yourdomain:8002/manage/v2/databases/yourdatabase?view=forest-storage
```

Comment: Yes. I get all that. It would just be nice to be able to put in an xpath and get targeted elements. 
     curl -s --anyauth -u admin:pass -X GET -i http : //myhost:8002/manage/v2/databases/mydb?uri=/database-default/relations/relation-group/relation/nameref/

Comment: Ahhh. You said only that you did not want the properties. I did not interpret that to mean just a list of values..

Comment: Thanks David. I used xquery and that worked. I was just hoping to use REST.

Comment: You could always use the REST eval endpoint with your custom xQuery

Comment: I have a perl mod script that runs the xquery function. I was trying to avoid adding another xquery function in my  admin:xquery but it ended up being easy to do.